# Java Script regexp for url vaidate with <>

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I wrote url validation function as bellow

```
Url = function (url) {
   var regexp = /^((http|https):\/\/)?(www[0-9]\.)?(([A-Za-z0-9_-])+\.{1})+([A-Za-z]{2,4})(\/([A-Za-z0-9_-])+)*(\/)?$/
   return regexp.test(url);
}
```

How can i change url validation method for user can enter variables like `<variable1>`, `<variable2>`, `<variable3>`(every variable start form `<` and end form `>`)

when user enter url `www.google.<variable1>` is want to be valid url (example for valid url `<variable1>.google.com`, `<variable1>`, `http://google.com/<variable1>`)

but user enter url as www.google.>variable1> is want to be invalid url
(example for invalid url: `>variable1<. google.com`, `variable1>`, `http://google.com/<variable1`)

This is basic JS question but im not good in RegExp so please help to me how can i allow to user can enter url with variables( `<myvariable>`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be as follows:

`^((http|https):\/\/)?(www[0-9]\.)?(([A-Za-z0-9_-])+\.{1})+([A-Za-z]{2,4}|\<[^<>]+\>)(\/([A-Za-z0-9_-])+)*(\/)?$`

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/bN9tA7

Comment: www.google.<<com> not valid url when `<` that want to be close using `>`

Comment: @Duleep, Wait so <<com> is __not__ valid or it __is__ valid?

Comment: Is not valid and same as <<value>> is not valid